# How to use "Revocable resource" in cluster (Spark + Mesos)

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

We tried to use "**Revocable resource**" option but no success due didn't find any information how to use it. So our question is: How to create a task in Spark (on Mesos) in right way to use "Revocable resource" option?

We found only this note:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17067 It contains info that Spark is support "Revocable resource" when working with Mesos.

Comment: Did you really read that JIRA??? It states clearly that in 2016, the proposed Spark feature was **blocked by a MESOS feature** _(that was never implemented)_ and in 2019 it was finally tagged as **not implemented, will never be implemented, forget it**

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. Thank you a lot for your comment !!!